# Automating ActiveMQ to enqueue when RESTful API is hit

Tags: java, rest, servlets, activemq-classic

I'd like to expose a public RESTful API and either configure our ActiveMQ instance (is possible) to listen at that API and automatically enqueue a JSON or XML version of those API calls, or configure/write software to translate the API call into a message and enqueue the message to an ActiveMQ queue/topic.

So, in other words:

1. A third party sends an HTTP request (GET/POST/PUT/whatever) to `http://myserver.com/api/enqueue`
2. Either:

   - ActiveMQ is somehow listening at `http://myserver.com/api/enqueue` and automatically enqueues a `toProcess` queue/topic with the API call's body; or
   - I have some kind of servlet listening at that URL and then pass the request on to some software (either open source Java library or something homegrown) that can extract the `HttpServletRequest`'s body and enqueue it to a queue/topic on the ActiveMQ server

So I ask: does ActiveMQ come with this capability out of the box (initial research indicates it *doesn't*), or are there any open source libraries that would do this for me, or some part of it for me? Or, am I stuck with a custom homegrown solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd write it yourself. Between Jersey, Jackson, and the ActiveMQ client you're talking about ... 20 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks @BrianRoach (+1) - do you know if Camel supports anything like this?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja Hey Dear, I have almost same requirments. I have developed a Rest API using Jersey. Now I have to implement Active MQ. I have to recieve each request from client and put it in to queue. So That it will process and not miss. Could you please give any idea on this. Thanks

Comment: may I have your email id..please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simple way, ActiveMQ actually does support HTTP/REST-ish interaction with queues [out of the box](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html).

As you did ask for Camel, yes, it does support creating more advanced REST API:s and works very well with ActiveMQ (actually, the Camel Core and JMS modulels is part of ActiveMQ distribution).

My favourite way to create REST APIs with Camel is through [restlets](http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html).

As Brian Roach said, this should be very straight forward to do in plain java code as well with some helper libs, so don't feel bad about a home grown thing here.